# Generate Telegram API sendMediaGroup request with bash

Tags: arrays, bash, gitlab-ci, telegram-api

I want to send all video files from current dir to Telegram from Gitlab CI. Image has no python or jq, I need to generate command from files list:

```
curl -F "chat_id=13245679" \
     -F 'media=[{"type": "video", "media": "attach://file1"}, {"type": "video", "media": "attach://file2" }]' \
     -F "file1=@/tmp/test1.txt" \
     -F "file2=@/tmp/test2.txt" \
     "https://api.telegram.org/bot<BOT-TOKEN>/sendMediaGroup"
```

I can create JSON like this:

```
export T=$(printf '{"type": "video", "media": "attach://%s"}, ' *)
-F "media=[${T::-1}]"
```

But I can't create list of attachments (like this `printf '-F "%s=@%s" ' *`).

Comment: What happens when you try? Is the output wrong, or is there an error message?

Comment: The result of `printf '-F "%s=@%s" ' *` is something like `-F 1.mp4=@2.mp4 -F 3.mp4=@4.mp4`, but I need `-F 1.mp4=@1.mp4 -F 2.mp4=@2.mp4...`

Comment: If it was Python, I could just zip * with * to get pairwise array like `1.mp4 1.mp4 2.mp4 2.mp4...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash implementation of `printf` doesn't support reuse of arguments. The format string `%s=@%s` will suck up two arguments at a time and repeat until all arguments are exhausted.

If we're sticking to bash, you can loop over the files and individually create an argument for each one. Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
form_args=()
for f in * ; do
  form_args+=( -F )
  form_args+=( "$( printf '%s=@%s' "$f" "$f" )" )
done
curl -F 'chat_id=13245679' -F 'media=...' "${form_args[@]}"
```